# How to reset the warning about "Chassis intrusion"?

Tags: windows, security

On my Windows 7 Dell from work, I got a message on boot this morning that said:

> Chassis intrusion detected.  This typically does NOT indicate a hardware failure.
>   1. Contact your Help Desk if you did not personally open your chassis.
>   2. Enter System Setup & Set Chassis Intrusion to 'Clear'.

Of course, I called our corporate help desk who confirmed that lots of people got this and it was due to some remotely-pushed BIOS upgrade not someone planting bugs inside the PC case. Now I want to reset the warming so it goes away. I'm not sure what "System Setup" they want me to enter, or how. It doesn't help that I have no idea what software produces this warning: some Googling told me that others have seen this (especially on Dells) but I didn't quickly find an explanation of how to reset the warning.

Does anyone know what produces this and how to reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter your BIOS and dig around for the reset intrusion button. Read what your screen says when first booting to find the correct key. Generally it's something like F2, F10 or Del. Keep hitting that key when you first boot your machine until it enters BIOS.